# Jquery How to add a counter for name attribute with dynamic added fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

Hello I have a form with these 2 fields where the user can add other fields dynamically.

```
 <section class="multi-field-wrapper">                          
 <h2>Ingredients</h2>
 <div class="multi-fields">
 <div class="f-row ingredient">
 <input type="text" name="ingredients[]"placeholder="Ingredients *"/>
 <input type="text"  name="quantity[]" placeholder="Quantity" />
 <button type="button" class="remove">-</button>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="f-row full">
 <button type="button" class="add">Add an ingredient</button>
 </div>
 </section>

<script>
$('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
    var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
    $(".add", $(this)).click(function(e) {
        $('.f-row.ingredient:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
   });
    $('.f-row.ingredient .remove', $wrapper).click(function() {

        if ($('.f-row.ingredient', $wrapper).length > 1)
            $(this).parent('.f-row.ingredient').remove();
    });
});
</script>


<script>
$('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
    var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
    $(".add", $(this)).click(function(e) {
        $('.f-row.instruction:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('')
    });
    $('.f-row.instruction .remove', $wrapper).click(function() {

        if ($('.f-row.instruction', $wrapper).length > 1)
            $(this).parent('.f-row.instruction').remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

**I am using **Jquery Validation Plugin and I have read all the threads before and I knew that I cannot use the SAME NAME for more than 1 input field.** All I need is a way to add a counter or index for the NAME attribute to the above JQUERY SCRIPT and **NOT** another script that append result in order to get something like this:

Field 1: ingredients[0]
Field 2: ingredients[1]
.......and so on

and how can I remove the index between the brackets after validation?

Thank you !

Comment: I didn't get your question.

Comment: the above code will validate only the first input field. in order to let the Jquery validation plugin to work and validate all the dynamic added fields. I need to give each input a unique name to do so I need to add a counter for the name attribute to make it unique.

Comment: You can name your variables as you did or some thing like ingredients1,ingredients2... for the validation, then you can on submit to join all your elements values to array/list, and send to server where your server method can accept list.

Comment: can you tell me how to it?